# Querying a collection of embeddable elements using eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have the following JPA (2.0.2) entities:

Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "T_COMPETENCE")
    private Set<Competence> competences;

    // Getter and setters
}
```

and Competence

```
@Embeddable
public class Competence {
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Skill skill;

    // Getter and setters
}
```

(The skill entity shouldn't be important and is therefore omitted, so are various additional attributes.)

I'm using EclipseLink (2.2.0) to query my entities with a DAO. Now I'd like to use the following query:

```
public List<Employee> findBySkill(Skill skill) {
    TypedQuery<Employee> query = getCurrentEntityManager().createQuery(
        "SELECT e FROM Employee e JOIN e.competences c WHERE c.skill = :skill", 
        Employee.class);
    query.setParameter("skill", skill);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

But it keeps throwing the following exception:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8030] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT e FROM Employee e JOIN e.competences c WHERE c.skill = :skill], line 1, column 54: unknown state or association field [skill] of class [com.kaio.model.Competence].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.unknownAttribute(JPQLException.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.DotNode.validate(DotNode.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.Node.validate(Node.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.BinaryOperatorNode.validate(BinaryOperatorNode.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.EqualsNode.validate(EqualsNode.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.WhereNode.validate(WhereNode.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.ParseTree.validate(ParseTree.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.ParseTree.validate(ParseTree.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.ParseTree.validate(ParseTree.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.JPQLParseTree.populateReadQueryInternal(JPQLParseTree.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.JPQLParseTree.populateQuery(JPQLParseTree.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1376)
    ... 48 more
```

The message is pretty clear: It can't find the attribute Skill on my class Competence. But in my opinion there is no reason on that. Or do I have a wrong approach on my problem? How should I query in a List of embeddable objects?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this seems to be a bug and it has been solved in a later version of eclipse link. I updated the project to EclipseLink 2.4 and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Competence` table will have a Skill.id field, so try:

```
"SELECT e FROM Employee e JOIN e.competences c WHERE c.skill.id = :skillId"

query.setParameter("skillId", skill.getId());
```

Comment: No, this can't work. Your syntax in JPQL means get me the id attribute of the skill attribute. Which will fail, as it can't even find the skill attribute. If I'd use the id's directly, I'd have to use a native sql query, but this is less than optimal.

Comment: But your query isn't fetching the skill entity. The ID would still be accessible because the Competence record (which is being fetched) will have a skill ID (referencing the skill table)

Comment: I already tried it out, it doesn't work ;) You don't have to fetch the skill entity. Actually the same query also fails, if I reference a basic attribute like a string. I debugged it into the intestines of eclispelink and it seems as the class competences has no attributes at all.